# how to change hyperlink's text in excel for a column

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have two columns here in my excel file: 
[image]

I am wondering that how can I get the following column? (combine these two columns together)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each hyperlink in the sheet has a new "friendly name" adjacent to it like:

[image]

Running this tiny macro:

```
Sub step2()
    Dim HY As Hyperlink
    For Each HY In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        HY.TextToDisplay = HY.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next HY
End Sub
```

will update the display of each hyperlink:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!